# Solr - How to write a query expression "every token produced by query analyzer Must occur"

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Solr 4.7. My index have a field "text"

if I enter the query

```
text:T1T2T3
```

assume that the analyzer output of T1T2T3 is token1=T1 token2=T2 token3=T3 (the language of text does not use space to split words ), the query is parsed to

```
text:T1 text:T2 text:T3
```

so if a field contains any of T1 or T2 or T3, it appears in search result.

What I want is that if a field contains T1 AND T2 AND T3, it appears in search result.

in other words, i want to write a query expression  (some operator)text:T1T2T3 which will be parsed to

```
+text:T1 +text:T2 +text:T3
```

I tried

```
+text:T1TT2T3   parsed to    +(text:T1 text:T2 text:T3)
```

"T1T2" will match. not good.

another try:

```
text:"T1T2T3"  parsed to   text:"T1 T2 T3"
```

"T1T4T2T5T3" won't match. not good.

How can I write a query that T1T2T3 can be parsed to +text:T1 +text:T2 +text:T3 which means every token produced by query analyzer Must occur? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need to write your own Custom CJK Tokenizer for this.

I was going to suggest NGram tokeniser, but it will generate all combinations, like: "BC", "DE", etc.

So probably you need to download Solr source code. Look at the implementation of the NGramTokenizer, and maybe implement you own tokenizer in Java and generate a jar file with your custom filter and use it.

Comment: Let me explain my question. Assume my analyzer split word correctly. I I have a query:  ApacheLucene. and three documents: Apache / Lucene / LuceneJavaApache. What I expected is that the search result contains only LuceneJavaApache.

Comment: I think maybe you will need to parse your query in your application and generate the query the way you intend, but I am not aware of solr functionality that will do that for you. Unless you want to implement your own query parser plugin in java, which will be a bit complex.